# Can I pass parameters using window load function once the whole window is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to call window.on('load') function after $.post success? How to pass

`val = data.result.state;`

to the load function.

Below is my code.

```
var u_id = <?= intval($_GET['id']);?>;

$.post('model/getUser.php',{id:u_id},function(data){
    if(data.success == true){
         if($("#country").val(data.result.country)){
            dochange('state', data.result.country);
            var val = data.result.state;
            $(window).on('load', function () {
                //
            });
         }
    }
},'json');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't the window have already loaded by the time your AJAX request completes (or even before it begins)?

Comment: Yes it is but I have to get that val after the window load function. Is there any way?

Comment: I posted this question based on my prev question. Sorry for duplicate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405973/second-dropdown-menu-not-selected

Comment: Just what do you think "on window load" means? Because I think you have the wrong idea

Comment: @Phil Regarding the previous question I want to set the value in the second dropdown menu. So I think about that. I didnot know I was doing wrong. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
(function($){  //This functions first parameter is named $
   $(window).load(function(){
       // Your code
   });
})(jQuery);    //Passing the jQuery object as a first argument
```